# React Native Login with cookies

Tags: react-native, cookies, fetch

i am trying to create a small app and i am logging in through an api which returns a cookie. I'm having problems locating and handling the cookie in my app. Any suggestions?

my fetch method:

```
async login() {
    try { 
        let response = await fetch('http://192.168.168.114:8090/Cam/LoginOut/role', {
            credentials: 'include',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              role: "CamTherapist",
              username: this.state.username,
              password: this.state.password
            })
        });
        let res = await response.text();
        if(response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
            let accessToken = res;
            console.log("res is + " + res);
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Idag');
        } else {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Idag');
            let errors = res;
            console.log(response.status + " fejl, Jeg er næsten inde");
            throw errors;
        }

    }   catch (errors) {
        console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ');
        // ADD THROW ERRORS EVENTUALLY
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are usually sent as a header called `Set-Cookie`.  You can locate your response headers using `response.headers`.

So, in order to locale your cookie:

```
let headers = response.headers
let newCookie = headers['Set-Cookie']
```

Note that the `Set-Cookie` header contains the cookie key, its value and also some further information such as the expiration date. You will need to parse the string to detect a specific piece of information.

It's important to note that in React Native fetch should support the cookies out-of-the-box, so you should already be able to use the cookie in your following requests, without any further code

Comment: that was exactly the info i needed to move on. from here i can use AsyncStorage. Thanks a lot man:)

Comment: Happy to help :)